# How to filter a List<object> for the latest values based on a given field

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of objects for my `Issue` class. Each object has a date stamp and a `Boolean` for whether or not the issue is still active.  For a given `Issue ID` (which refers to another collection elsewhere), there can be multiple entries with either true or false, I am only concerned with the *latest true* value.

From this list, I need to get a list of all ids for items that have true in their *latest* value.  I have implemented this in what seems to be a crazy inefficient manner.  I would figure there must be a more streamlined approach:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var IssueList = new List<Issue>();

        // Add four Issues
        IssueList.Add(new Issue() { labelId = "1", Result = false, AuditDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1), Note = "No: Latest, but false" });
        IssueList.Add(new Issue() { labelId = "1", Result = true, AuditDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-6), Note = "No: Superceeded" });
        IssueList.Add(new Issue() { labelId = "1", Result = false, AuditDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5), Note = "No: Superceeded" });
        IssueList.Add(new Issue() { labelId = "2", Result = true, AuditDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-6), Note = "Yes: Latest and True" });

        // Get the unique ids
        var ids = (from id in IssueList.OfType<Issue>()
                   select id.labelId).Distinct();

        // Process each id in a loop and get the latest Issue for each id
        List<Issue> latestList = new List<Issue>();
        foreach (string id in ids)
        {
            // Get a new collection with the most recent Issue for each id
            List<Issue> idFiltered = IssueList.Where(i => i.labelId == id).ToList().OrderBy(o => o.AuditDate).ToList();

            latestList.Add(idFiltered.LastOrDefault());
        }

        // Get just the True values
        List<Issue> trueList = latestList.Where(r => r.Result == true).ToList();

        // Get the Ids (Distinct should be redudant here)
        List<string> theIds = (from id in trueList.OfType<Issue>()
                               select id.labelId).Distinct().ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to quit");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private class Issue
    {
        public Issue() { }
        public string labelId { get; set; }
        public bool Result { get; set; }
        public DateTime AuditDate { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The list correctly returns only the id 2, but I figure there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

```
var trueIdList = IssueList.OfType<Issue>()
           .GroupBy(c => c.labelId)
           .Select(c => c.OrderBy(o => o.AuditDate).LastOrDefault())
           .Where(c => c.Result)
           .Select(c => c.labelId)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Why LastOrDefault, when the collection can not be empty? Anyway, MaxBy is better, no need to sort everything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in two parts.

First, find the latest item from each *group* of items, grouped by ID:

```
var latest = 
    from issue in IssueList.OfType<Issue>()
    group issue by issue.labelId into grp
    select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.AuditDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

And then isolate the list of items that have the `Result` member set:

```
var ids = 
    from issue in latest 
    where issue.Result 
    select issue.labelId;
```

Functionally this is equivalent to chsword's answer, but I think it is slightly clearer to do it in two parts to highlight the way it functions.